# pam_systemd Failed to create session: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ssh, systemd, pam, proxmox

This error message keeps repeating over and over in my Ubuntu 14.04 system logs. Appears to be related to an automated ssh connection.  Anyone know what file/directory `systemd` is missing or how to get more info about it? Found a [Thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1318168l) on Launchpad about it but no fix. All latest patches are applied on this system.

```
sshd[23824]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: No such file or directory
```

**update** added pic of pam auth config
[image]

Comment: What is the PAM configuration?

Comment: Thanks. unchecked *Register user sessions...* and *ConsoleKit* (unmaintained according to freedesktop web page) and *Inheritiable Capabilities Management*. Seems to have stopped. Any idea what ICM is for?

Comment: No idea about ICM, but it was probably "register user sessions", which suggests something is wrong with your kernel. What kernel version are you running? Or is this a Proxmox container as it was when you asked a virtually identical question the other day?

Comment: Yeah, Proxmox container again. Actually there were a couple problems with `ssh` and `cgroup` on these containers I've asked about here. I don't know what the root cause is but about to give up on the containers. They've been nothing but problems.

Comment: My guess is it doesn't work precisely because it's in a proxmox container. While cgroups can be namespaced so that they work in containers, I can't tell whether Proxmox actually can do this (and it's clear from your description that it currently does not). You might need to seek help from a Proxmox-specific support channel.